# HTML/CSS Div Extending Beyond Its Closing Tag

Tags: css, html, styling

On a web page I'm creating, the page is dynamically generated by a PHP-based CMS. The CMS fetches all the information for the page from a database, then echoes the correct HTML tags etc onto the page.

The problem I have is that for some reason my browser is extending a div beyond it's closing tag.

IE: even though I can see the tag closes, the browser doesn't appear to, so any styling applied within that `div` are being applied to the whole page.

Below is the HTML output. (This is an extract of the page, and the header div is the one that's persisting).

```
<div id="header">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 10%;">
    <img style="height: 120px; width: 101px;" src="img" alt="some alt">
   </td>
   <td>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <h3>Subhead</h3>
   </td>
  </tr>
 <table>
</div>
<div id="menubar">
```

I've also included the opening of the next `div`.

If I try and style the `h2` and `h3` inside of the `div`, all of the `h2` and `h3` tags on the page are affected. Here's my CSS:

```
#header h2 {
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #776F65;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

#header h3 {
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #776F65;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    padding-left: 35px;
}
```

And finally, here's the PHP code I use to generate the HTML output:

```
echo('<div id="header">'); // HEADER ELEMENT BEGINS HERE
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getHeaderElements)) {
        echo($row['content']);
    }
echo('</div>'); // End Header Element.
```

The browser I'm using is Google Chrome.

Does anybody know why this strange behavior is occurring?

Regards,
Ben.

Comment: You haven't closed your `<table>` tag properly - it seems to have been closed with another opening tag. Try fixing that and see if your problem is solved.

Comment: That second table tag suppossed to be</table> instead of <table> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "end" tag for the `<table>` is actually a start tag for another table.

This error is probably the cause of your problem.

[Validate](http://validator.w3.org) your markup, it's a cheap way to pick up this sort of error.

Comment: I should have really. I just glanced over it and saw a table tag at the end of the table and assumed it was a close tag. Thanks!